# How can I find the desktop directory from a script, even if it was relocated out of the user profile?

Tags: windows-10, shell-script, desktop, folder-redirection

To conserve space on the SSD with my Windows installation (C:), I have folders such as the Desktop for each user relocated to a separate HDD (D:), using the graphical interface.

Consequently, I cannot use `%userprofile%\Desktop` to get at the actual Desktop, because it expands to the nonexistent `C:\Users\User Name\Desktop`, when it should instead refer to `D:\Users\User Name\Desktop`.

How can I fix this? How do I get at the actual Desktop location? I want something general-purpose so that my scripts can run on other people's computers if they've done similar things with other drive letters. (Also, why doesn't Windows implement this relocation using a symlink or similar?)

Comment: Well, there probably isn't a good option using Env vars (there is no predefined variable for desktop). Could you use the All Users profile desktop instead? that should put stuff on your desktop without you needing to find the users desktop folder.

Comment: Part of what I'm trying to do is to create a separate "workspace" folder on each user's own desktop, so no - they shouldn't share contents. The information has to be recorded *somewhere*, right? After all, Explorer knows where everything is. I'm prepared to dig into the Registry if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print out the path.

To Use

```
cscript //nologo "C:\Folder\GetUserDesktopPath.vbs"
```

File contents

```
wscript.echo CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(&h10).self.path
```

To parse it (use `%%A` in a batch file and `%A` interactively).

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('cscript //nologo "C:\Folder\Test.vbs"') Do echo %A
```

See for technical documentation

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath

Comment: Thanks. The hint about `shgetknownfolderpath` is what I needed. I had been hoping to use either Python or plain batch - I searched around some more and found what seem to be equivalent Python wrappers via [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851281/python-finding-the-users-downloads-folder). Cheers!